# Why MSBuild only uses one core while VS.NET uses up all the cores available on the same .sln?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, msbuild, build

Our solution consists of about 20 .vcproj files. Except for the main program, most of them are independent libraries which only have dependency from their own unit tests.

When we build this solution in VS.NET, we notice VS starts multiple VCBuildHelper process and efficiently uses up all the cores available. However, when we run our daily build scripts implemented with MSBuild, we notice that only one core is used.

We had added /maxcpucount and /p:BuildInParallel=true, but it still didn't work.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Parallel builds is surprisingly non-trivial, as MSVS does an interesting "order-of-projects" decision to run some things in parallel, and others not.  From what you describe, though, it seems like you should have seen more parallelism.

Here's a post from the MSBuild team talking about tuning parallelism:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msbuild/archive/2010/03/08/tuning-c-build-parallelism-in-vs2010.aspx

Here's a YieldDuringToolExecution tool to get better parallelism (MSBuild 4):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msbuild/archive/2010/06/03/better-parallelism-in-msbuild-4-with-yieldduringtoolexecution.aspx

A little more dated, here's a blogger hack on getting better parallelism inside the IDE:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HackParallelMSBuildsFromWithinTheVisualStudioIDE.aspx

Which MSVS version are you using?

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks for your replying! We use MSVS 2008 here. I'm experimenting with your reference articles now. I'll post the final solution for my situation if any of them do the trick.

Comment: We're still MSVS 2008 here too.  We have installed MSVS2010, but it has performance and other issues, and we can't cut to it yet.  (I'd guess you could get as-good-or-better parallelism in MSVS2008 over MSVS2010.)  -- Thanks, I'd be interested in your "final" solution for your situation, if you find it.

Answer (score 0):

We had experimented various ways and have no luck. Now we got back to our old friend: **devenv xxx.sln /build configuration**, and it gave us the same parallelism as we had in IDE.

I believe there must be missing pieces hidden somewhere. I just have no time to figure it out :(